# Save images in browser and send them with ajax with only one inputfield

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to make a multiple image upload script, but i only wants one input field.

When a image has been choosen, the image should be displayed as a preview. I need to save the image somehow, and sent the data to a PHP script which handles the rest.

I've created a jsfiddle to illustrate how it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ETayz/7/

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I dont know how to store the images so i can send them to a PHP script